# Can't deploy Visual Studio extension

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I have Visual Studio 2015 and Modelling SDK extension installed. 
I try to deploy the project by executing .vsix file as it is said in MSDN instruction.

But I get a message

> 9/17/2017 4:59:03 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have tried debug your extension in VS2015 without any issues? Please debug it to go to the type "VSIXInstaller.App", method "private void InitializeInstall()". That method contains the logic that searches for applicable SKUs and along with the InitializeUninstall is the only method that throws above error. Detailed troubleshooting steps, please refer to: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/91c39d64-6d51-41a5-8fc6-bc2bef6394df/this-extension-is-not-installable-on-any-currently-installed-products?forum=vsx

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
Do I need to debug? My app is good in debugging mode. Everything is working. But when I try to deploy it, I mean, to execute .vsix file it throws me the error.

Comment: Do you have tried the troubleshooting steps in the link I provided? The error message means your .VSIX file doesn't find Visual Studio product on your machine. So please check the installation log file and check whether there has any problem when it finds the Visual Studio product.